# Removing the last occurence of an element from a list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a program that removes the last occurrence of an element from a list in Prolog. I am not supposed to use built in predicates here, except for member/2.
I understand that I have to use recursion for this. But I'm not awfully good with it. I got as far as this, but it fails:

```
% remove_last/3 with (Element, List, Resultlist)
remove_last(X,[X|T],NT):-
   remove_last(X,T,NT).
```

I figure that Prolog is supposed to cut of the head of the list, scan the tail, do it over again until the tail matches with the Element, delete that and restore the remainder list. But I don't know how to put this in code. 
I would appreciate any tips!

Comment: What if an element occurs only once?

Comment: What if the element doesn't occur at all? Shoud the predicate fail?

Comment: @lurker: What is too broad here?

Comment: @false I had flagged this question before there was any code sample or anything other details posted. It was, at the time too broad/vague. The OP subsequently edited the question and added more detail. I've voted to reopen on the basis of the edit.

Comment: @lurker: So now reopen...

Comment: @false I can only vote to reopen. I cannot reopen.

Comment: @lurker: That's good enough!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a much more readable answer:

```
remove_last(X, [X|L], L) :-
    maplist(dif(X), L).
remove_last(X, [H|T], [H|L]) :-
    remove_last(X, T, L).
```

Obviously it uses built-ins which is apparently forbidden but I would argue that `dif/2` is so important it might as well be considered as legal as e.g. `\+` for things like this (same for `maplist`).

It behaves pretty nicely:

```
?- remove_last(2,[1,2,3,2,5],Z).               % "Normal" use
Z = [1, 2, 3, 5] ;
false

?- remove_last(Z,[1,2,3,2,5],[1,2,3,5]).       % Searching X given the two lists
Z = 2 ;
false.

?- remove_last(2,X,[1,2,3,5]).                 % Searching the original list
X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 5, 2] ;
false.
```

If everything is a variable, it kind of works but doesn't enumerate answers properly:

```
?- remove_last(X,L,M).
L = [X],
M = [] ;
L = [X, _1124],
M = [_1124],
dif(X, _1124) ;
L = [X, _1302, _1308],
M = [_1302, _1308],
dif(X, _1308),
dif(X, _1302) ;
…
```

You can make it enumerate answers properly using `length/2`:

```
?- length(L, _), remove_last(X,L,M).
L = [X],
M = [] ;
L = [X, _1230],
M = [_1230],
dif(X, _1230) ;
L = [_692, X],
M = [_692] ;
L = [X, _1408, _1414],
M = [_1408, _1414],
dif(X, _1414),
dif(X, _1408) ;
L = [_1242, X, _1254],
M = [_1242, _1254],
dif(X, _1254) ;
L = [_692, _698, X],
M = [_692, _698] ;
```

#### Run time

On a list of 1000 random digits:

```
?- time(remove_last(3,[8,1,5,1,8,2,0,1,8,2,0,4,2,1,6,8,6,1,0,3,5,6,3,5,3,1,8,7,7,4,8,8,0,9,3,8,7,9,0,6,4,8,1,9,2,9,0,1,0,0,9,7,7,5,2,5,8,5,1,6,8,3,2,8,7,2,9,0,5,9,5,0,9,6,7,1,4,9,7,1,3,5,0,0,0,3,3,7,7,7,9,4,9,8,0,8,7,0,7,7,0,8,3,0,9,3,4,8,8,1,3,7,8,8,8,2,7,4,2,8,4,0,6,9,3,9,0,2,0,7,9,5,9,0,8,3,3,4,3,4,2,3,0,4,6,8,9,3,6,0,9,7,6,4,8,7,3,8,9,5,4,2,7,2,9,3,0,5,3,7,9,0,3,4,5,3,5,0,9,4,4,5,2,9,0,9,2,6,1,6,3,4,6,3,9,9,0,6,0,7,9,3,8,3,0,7,1,3,5,4,9,1,9,0,4,8,2,5,3,7,5,7,2,7,3,2,1,7,9,3,9,3,6,4,3,6,9,8,1,3,7,6,0,8,0,4,6,6,4,4,8,5,1,8,5,9,1,7,6,2,8,0,2,5,0,7,2,7,9,2,6,7,6,2,8,2,1,9,2,5,6,8,0,2,2,2,3,2,0,6,9,5,7,3,8,9,9,6,9,9,3,3,7,5,9,0,2,2,6,3,7,1,4,7,4,0,9,1,1,5,2,2,3,4,7,8,8,3,4,1,2,6,8,2,8,0,0,7,5,6,5,9,0,6,5,6,4,0,4,5,6,7,4,5,1,5,9,9,9,3,6,1,0,6,8,6,0,6,6,0,9,4,2,3,8,8,8,4,3,0,4,7,1,4,7,7,4,6,6,3,0,0,7,1,5,1,6,2,9,1,3,5,0,6,6,4,8,7,0,6,3,7,0,0,8,6,9,3,1,2,6,2,6,1,0,1,7,4,6,4,3,9,2,5,5,7,4,1,8,8,1,3,8,0,9,0,9,7,5,5,9,6,6,3,8,3,1,5,9,5,1,0,6,7,1,5,0,4,7,1,1,4,4,9,5,8,4,2,1,5,3,2,4,6,8,6,8,6,9,5,5,7,3,6,0,6,0,3,8,0,0,5,1,8,7,3,9,9,3,2,6,7,4,2,6,5,4,2,6,8,6,2,2,3,5,0,5,2,8,5,4,0,0,3,5,0,8,2,0,1,7,3,0,2,4,3,8,4,9,5,2,5,9,1,3,4,3,3,6,7,7,3,6,0,8,8,4,1,3,9,0,1,3,3,4,0,8,4,2,5,1,0,5,2,5,2,3,1,2,3,9,3,5,2,8,7,9,3,4,0,0,7,5,1,7,5,8,2,6,4,8,4,7,0,5,9,7,3,4,8,9,6,4,1,8,6,8,5,0,0,8,9,2,5,8,0,0,6,8,1,9,3,7,2,6,3,3,4,0,4,1,6,3,7,5,2,5,8,9,8,1,7,1,5,2,8,7,5,8,3,7,4,9,6,2,3,7,1,0,2,9,9,3,3,2,9,6,0,3,4,0,4,4,4,5,1,3,2,6,7,5,7,9,4,4,4,1,9,7,4,0,5,2,6,1,2,4,4,7,3,8,9,2,8,0,3,1,5,0,7,7,8,1,9,6,1,9,4,9,7,6,4,0,2,1,7,9,0,8,9,9,6,6,3,7,8,7,1,1,7,3,3,4,4,8,0,2,1,1,7,2,6,8,6,2,1,2,2,4,7,5,9,3,4,4,9,3,0,8,4,4,4,5,8,0,2,5,5,0,6,2,1,7,4,0,7,1,6,4,3,9,0,1,1,0,9,3,0,7,1,2,8,4,0,2,7,2,8,6,5,1,8,0,0,4,5,6,0,1,9,6,1,5,1,9,0,0,2,7,1,2,4,1,2,0,8,9,1,4,7,3,1,1,8,8,4,4,5,8,0,0,5,0,9,7,1,1,5,1,6,4,0,4,8,7,0,2,7,9,1,4,6,2,8,9,1,6,1,4,0,7,9,9,9,0,6,8,8,2,0,4,4,6,0,0,2,0,0,6,4,6,2,5,5,7,7,8,1,9,6,6,6,7,8,5,7,0,1,0,9,1,4,2,1,7,2,1,6,7,6,4,7,5,7,7,7,4,4,2,6,7,1,1,3,3,7,6,2,9,8,9,9,2,4,7,2,2,8,8,3,3,6,4,2,4,4,5,4,0,8,3,4,6,5,3,1,1,0,3,0],Z)).
% 10,996 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.002 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
Z = [8, 1, 5, 1, 8, 2, 0, 1, 8|...] .
```

Comment: What is the runtime cost? Is there some O(n^2) lurking?

Comment: @false Just a quick experiment, using the predicate in the expected direction by OP and selecting the penultimate element: takes 1047 inferences compared to Willem's 312 inferences (0 ms for both) for a list of 100 elements. For a list of 1000 elements, 10k inferences (2 ms) compared to 3k inferences (1 ms). So it seems to have a similar behavior to Willem's answer.

Comment: Please give the precise query, I suspect, you left out some inferences...

Comment: @false Given in the answer.

Comment: @lurker: it is impossible to define this without some built-in predicate.

Comment: @Fatalize: I still suspect that it is somehowt possible to get non-linear cost. Clearly: If the element occurs too early, it's linear. If the element occurs at the end, that's linear too. But somewhere in the middle...

Comment: @false technically, yes, but this sort of question is asked a lot (about not using a built-in predicate) and it has a particular meaning, which is that they want to limit the solution to more basic predicates.

Comment: @lurker: It's still impossible and thus a completely undesirable situation for a beginner: being asked to do something that is impossible

Comment: @false I've tried with a list of 1000 digits, the first half being random digits between 0 and 9, and the second half between 0 and 8. Removing 9 results in pretty much the same running time (10,970 inferences).

Comment: @Fatalize: We'd need a slightly more analytical approach.

Comment: @false We would, but I don't have a good enough grasp of Prolog to do so in a reasonable time. I especially have no idea about the complexity of `dif/2` depending on its inputs.

Comment: @Fatalize: Just consider the case where the first two arguments are ground and the second argument is a list of characters only. I suspect (but cannot prove it) that there are some non-linear cases hidden in between.